# Why is my MySQL going offline?

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have 2 applications hosted in a windows server 2008 r2 (AWS EC2 Large instance)machine, using IIS7.5 and mysql 5.5.12. The one database is hosted on the server with a local DB instance the other DB instance is an Amazon RDS instance. Strangely, both were affected by the issue below:

I got an error:

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system
>   lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

I was able to resolve the issue, by restarting the machine as well as the database instance (on other machine - AWS RDS) But I'd like to understand why it happend.

Are there known issues with MySQL memory? I notice when I look at the task manager I see two instances of 'mysqld' running at 2.5Gb and 3Gb RAM each. This sounds excessive for a mostly inactive databases of about 15 Mb data each. Also is it normal to have two tasks running when I only have one DB hosted locally, and the other is in AWS RDS (seperate server).

Answer (score 0):

A quick search returned the MSDN [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2009/03/09/understanding-the-error-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full.aspx) which suggests that this is Windows problem not the MySQL.

1. OS runs out of memory for TCP buffers
2. OS runs out of available TCP "ephemeral" ports

You may read another relevant post [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fd27e588-4a1d-4f3c-882a-9e95dabce794/windows-2008-r2-64bit-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space).

Comment: He said that the database is mostly inactive, so I don't know how valid this is.

Comment: The blog post claims a x86/ windows server 2003 and earlier is affected and it is also listed as a sql server issue. My relevant technologies are neither of those. While it might be true that the error is originating from the operating system. I suspect the cause is MySQL which is using alot of memory.